# Text resized in Webview, but not on chrome

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm loading my website into a webview, and all the text elements' font sizes are increased by a factor of 1.375. It works fine on chrome on the same device but is looking completely wrong on a webview inside the app.

I read font-boosting is one of the causes of this, but why is the webview resizing perfectly legible text of size 24px to 33px?

I'm using android 4.4 to test the app.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I have the answer. You need to set `WebSettings.setTextZoom` to 100 if you want to retain the original functions. This call only works API level 14 and above, before that you can use `TextSize`